# Need an auto-complete plugin for codeceptjs

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, codeceptjs

I am very new to `Codeceptjs`. I'm using Visual Studio Code to write some sample tests. It will really help me if I could have something like an auto-complete for the methods so when I typed for instance `I.see` it shows me the options that I have, for instance, `seeInCurrentUrl`.
Tried but couldn't find any plugins for VSC do you know any? or any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs. You can add the definitions by doing https://codecept.io/commands#typescript-definitions

You run

```
npx codeceptjs def
```

to install the auto-complete definitions and then add

```
/// <reference path="./steps.d.ts" />
```

at the top of each file. Hope that helps.

Comment: I propose to add the actual command to run „npx codeceptjs def“ to your answer to improve it, just like to the docs as reference.

Answer (score -1):

In steps_file.ts, try to change the following line:

```
// module.exports = function() {
export = function() {
    return actor({
        // Define custom steps here, use 'this' to access default methods of I.
        // It is recommended to place a general 'login' function here.
    })
}
```